# Parse Server not recognizing APP_ID

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I have installed Parse Server on Heroku and forked the [Parse Server Example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example). When I `git push heroku master` I get the error

> "You must provide an appIp!"

Error log:

```
019-03-20T11:03:56.517489+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-20T11:03:59.418738+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-20T11:03:59.418754+00:00 app[web.1]: > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
2019-03-20T11:03:59.418756+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-03-20T11:03:59.418757+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-20T11:04:01.887096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-20T11:04:01.724008+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-20T11:04:01.724030+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:218
2019-03-20T11:04:01.724032+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-03-20T11:04:01.724033+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-20T11:04:01.724105+00:00 app[web.1]: You must provide an appId!
2019-03-20T11:04:01.779713+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-20T11:04:01.780520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 7
2019-03-20T11:04:01.782955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
2019-03-20T11:04:01.783173+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 7
2019-03-20T11:04:01.783716+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-20T11:04:01.783983+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script.
2019-03-20T11:04:01.784194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-20T11:04:01.804701+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-20T11:04:01.805007+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-03-20T11:04:01.805196+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-03-20T11_04_01_786Z-debug.log
2019-03-20T11:04:01.866235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 7
```

`index.js`:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
    var path = require('path');

    var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

    if (!databaseUri) {
      console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
    }

var api = new ParseServer({
      databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://key
      cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
      appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
      masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey', 
      serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://myApp.herokuapp.com/parse',
      liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
      }

    });

     var server = ParseServer({
      verifyUserEmails: true,
    publicServerURL: 'myApp.herokuapp.com/parse',
    appName: 'myAppName',
    emailAdapter: { 
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: { 
                   fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
                   domain: 'domainFromMailGun.mailgun.org', 
                   apiKey: 'myAPIKey', 
                 }
     }
     });
```

I have provided the `appId` in `appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',`  or am I missing something here? Does the `appId` have to provided elsewhere?

Comment: You've just leaked your MongoDB connection string. If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. There's no need to include that in your code (and indeed you probably shouldn't) since you're already loading it from the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please invalidate those MongoDB credentials ***immediately***. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is **not enough**.

---

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do here, but you're actually instantiating *two* Parse servers. You do provide an `appId` for the first one (`api`), but not for the second (`server`).

You probably only need one Parse Server. If you do actually need two for some reason, each one will need an `appId`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.. That question was a total fail. I'm sorry for being a muppet! I have edited the question to contain the actual issue.